# Where are the radiation models for Japan catastrophe?

Tags: modelling

I'm interested in seeing authoritative model results showing how radioactive contaminants from Japan might circulate through wind and water.

[image: map lie]
The [AGU blog points out](http://blogs.agu.org/wildwildscience/2011/03/15/false-radiation-rumors-run-rampant/) this bad model, but in skimming the sites they reference I didn't see any other models.  I see no mention of radiation at [NOAA's Global Forecast System](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/nwprod/analysis/). Where are the reputable models?

Comment: Not definite model, but might be of interest: http://singularityhub.com/2011/03/24/japans-nuclear-woes-give-rise-to-crowd-sourced-radiation-maps-in-asia-and-us/

Comment: Also some additional pointers @ O'REILLY radar: http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/03/japan-radiation-visualizations.html

Comment: Few more: https://healthmap.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/japan-radiation-levels-mapped/

Comment: Interesting initiative in crowdsourcing http://news.cnet.com/japan-radiation-monitoring-goes-crowd-open-source/8301-17938_105-20060639-1.html

Answer (score 11):

Here's a [model published by NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2011/03/16/science/plume-graphic.html?ref=science), linked to from [this article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/17/science/17plume.html).

Update
Paul Kedrosky [says](http://www.bloomberg.com/blogs/paul-kedrosky/2011/03/latest-japan-radiation-trajectory-models.html) ...

> "There was an irresponsible piece in
>   the New York Times last night
>   suggesting that radiation from Japan’s
>   Fukushima reactor could be in
>   California by tomorrow"

He likes Jeff Masters [blog post](http://www.wunderground.com/blog/JeffMasters/comment.html?entrynum=1766) about to this NOAA model better.  I think the public needs a weatherman dancing and waving hands in front of a [chroma key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) map of model results to effectively communicate probabilities.  Perhaps Morten Nielsen's [kinect tool](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/03/18/ESRI-DevSummit-2011e28093overnout.aspx) could be used by analysts to mashup their own interpretive dance on top of a map video.

[image]

Comment: Anyone know why random clouds start appearing over California on 3/17?

Comment: Two of the links in this post result in 404 errors.

Answer (score 5):

One from the [Belgian Institute for Space Aeronomy](http://www.aeronomie.be/):

[image]

Comment: +1 for a bit of hope, no idea if its accurate though.

Answer (score 5):

Here the ZAMG model as of today: [image: Fukushima plume end of March 2011]http://www.zamg.ac.at/pict/aktuell/20110329_fuku_I-131.gif (go to their [main page](http://www.zamg.ac.at))

Answer (score 1):

http://www.irsn.fr/FR/Actualites_presse/Actualites/Page/20110319_simulation_dispersion_panache_radioactif.aspx

http://www.mesure-radioactivite.fr/public/spip.php?page=carte

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best suite of models for atmospheric dispersion, especially of nuclear materials, is from [NARAC](https://narac.llnl.gov/) of the [Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory](http://www.llnl.gov). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any public results attributed to NARAC. If you have business or public safety mission needs, you may a be able to get access to NARAC model results if available.